# Ambari can't get hadoop job history

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm managing hadoop cluster with hortonworks ambari. (HDP1.3)

But Ambari management site's jobs view can't display any jobs.

But hadoop_host:51111/jobhistoryhome.jsp site can display jobs well.

I debug ambari web and find that

```
"ambari_server:8080/api/v1/jobhistory/datatable?iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&iSortCol_0=8&sSortDir_0=DESC"
```

returned `{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":0,"iTotalDisplayRecords":0,"startIndex":-1,"endIndex":-1,"aaData":[],"summary":{"numRows":0,"jobs":{"avg":0.0,"min":0,"max":0},"input":{"avg":0.0,"min":0,"max":0},"output":{"avg":0.0,"min":0,"max":0},"duration":{"avg":0.0,"min":0,"max":0},"times":{"oldest":0,"youngest":0}}}`

Why Ambari can't get hadoop job history data?

(I installed Ambari with "root" user and run hadoop job with "hadoop" user.)
(Hadoop cluster run inside firewall then each host can't access internet.)